# Laravel strtotime not showing correct time

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I'm having a strange issue with formatting my times properly. I'm not getting remotely close to my time entries values at all.

I'm grouping the times by categories and months, and i'm formatting the times to have no leading zeros and no seconds.

Some example outputs are:
If any of my time entries are before 10:00:00 (So double digits for hours)
The formatted time will be 00:00

e.g 09:45:00 will be formatted to 00:00:00, when it should be **9:45**
11:00:00 is formatted to 12:00:00 etc, i'm not sure whats happening here.

```
 public function show(User $user) 
    {
        $data = collect(array_fill(1, 12, []))
            ->replace(
                $user->times()
                    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
                    ->groupBy('category_id', \DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->select([
                        'category_id',
                        \DB::raw('month(start_day) as month'),
                        \DB::raw('sum(duration) as duration'),
                    ])
                    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->get()
                    ->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
                        return [$item['month'] => [
                            $item['category_id'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])
                        ]];
                    })
                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
                        return [$key => $item->collapse()];
                    })
            )
            ->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
                $month = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $key)->format('M');
                return [$month => $item];
            });

        return view('report.show', compact('data'));
    }
private function formatDuration($duration)
{

    $duration = strtotime($duration);

    return date('g:i',$duration);
}
```

Comment: Double-check what's going in and out. Try `Log::info($duration);` at the beginning of your `formatDuration` function, then `Log::info(date('g:i',$duration));` before you return it. Then check your logs in `/storage/logs` to see if the data you're passing through looks correct.

Comment: Isn't `sum(duration)` an SQL command to sum the field? That part looks suspicious, as the comment before mentioned, try debugging it and see what it's showing. You can also use the function dd() not to bother with Logs.

Comment: Well i'm summing all entries for each category, but when I'm testing it I'm only using 1 entry per category. And yea i've been using dd for debugging and just ending up with strange time entries. I'll try logging it and see what happens.

Comment: @aynber Ok, so I wiped my migrations and added one time entry, with a duration of: 09:00:00.
When I log $duration in the beginning, I get a value of: "90000".
Then when I log date('g:i',$duration), I get a value of  "12:00". When it should be "9:00"

Comment: "90000" doesn't seem like a valid number. I can't even get `strtotime` to work with that, so `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $duration);` is returning `1969-12-31 19:00:00` for me

Comment: Could it be a problem with my queries?

Comment: Maybe? Check what the duration is, coming from your query. It should be in H:i:s format and not a whole number.